# Phantom Local Disks appearing in my drive list

Tags: windows-7, local, disk-management

I seem to have several phantom Local Disks mapped to different letters that are of 0 bytes in size.

Strangely, they do not show up when I view my drives through Windows Explorer. But if I open an application such as ACDSee Pro or Microsoft Word and then go to open a file I can see all these Local Disks mapped to different letters.

This means when I plug in my external hard disk it ends up mapped to letter R instead of its usual G which messes up any programs I have pointing to it by default.

How did they get there and more importantly, how do I get rid of them?

I'm on a Windows 7 Home Premium 32 bit machine.

Answer (score 3):

Although not fixing the problem here is a bit more info on it...

Office 2010 Beta - Phantom Q drive  (only if you have the phantom Q drive)

http://technicalmeltdown.wordpress.com/2009/12/18/office-2010-beta-adds-local-disk-q-to-the-system/
http://technicalmeltdown.wordpress.com/2009/12/26/hide-local-disk-q-added-by-office-2010-beta/

Can use Tweak UI for XP to get rid of phantom drives

Long forum discussion on the problem but mainly refers to XP users
http://forums.techguy.org/hardware/467043-problems-phantom-drive-letters.html

Answer (score 0):

If you remap the phantom drives to later in the alphabet they won't disrupt the letters assigned to removable disks;

1. Control Panel, Administrative Tools
2. Computer Management
3. Disk Management
4. Right-click on a disk and select "Change letter and paths..."

Comment: thanks for the reply - unfortunately they don't appear in the disk management list.