# I have a "ghost drive" Local Disk (Q:) under my "Hard Disk Drives" category which cannot be deleted

Tags: windows, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New partition has been made automatically](https://superuser.com/questions/391680/new-partition-has-been-made-automatically)

I think it happened after I connected my dad's external hard drive to my PC. Its capacity is 0 bytes, it cannot be formatted, and under Disk Management I can't find it. How do I remove it?

Comment: Can you find it under Device Manager?

Comment: Where under Device Manager do you look?

Comment: I've got same problem. This drive is not visible in Disk management. As for Device Manager - not sure, nothing apparent there.

Answer (score 1):

As alexeit's answer/link refers to, it's probably Office 2010, there are various utilities that can hide it from the list of drives- like the TweakUI Powertoy for one.

Comment: So its MS Office 2010? Oh ok, talk about scaring the hell out of me, usually you see Root kits doing that kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

Office starter 2010, home and office , home and business and started to go (which came preinstalled in many systems), use a form of application virtualisation (app-v/click 2 run). One of the side effects of this is that it creates a Q: which you have you have no access to.

Microsoft has a [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982434) on click 2 run here and basically warns against hiding or storing anything in that drive - so you might want to, ideally just ignore the presense of the drive rather than trying to hide it.

This is an older question, but I rather doubt it has anything to do with the external drive in question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out answer in this question about drive Q

[Phantom Local Disks appearing in my drive list](https://superuser.com/questions/129753/phantom-local-disks-appearing-in-my-drive-list)