# New partition has been made automatically

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I've just noticed a new partition which I never made:

[image]

What's this? Isn't it probably caused by a virus or something?

Comment: that screenshot is not really informative. it could be anything, the normal win7-boot partition, some recovery partition, could be even a malfunctioning USB-device that erroniously registers as a drive but is none. 
What does the partition manager show? Start -> Control Panel -> System and Security -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Storage -> Disk Management (needs admin rights for that)

Comment: @WalterMaier-Murdnelch: Mokubai's answer is correct, I downloaded it some days ago. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you have no use for the Virtual Q drive, it can be removed, go to Control Panel (icon view) > Programs and Features, uninstall "Microsoft Application Virtualization Desktop Client", the Q drive should be gone, it may require a restart of the PC before it is gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This drive is created by the Office "Click to Run" program.  It creates the Q: drive when you run an Office app.

From the Microsoft [Knowledgebase](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982434)

> Office Click-to-Run products also use Microsoft virtualization technology that stores Office 2010 in virtualized application space. This virtual space separates Office 2010 from the regular file system and from the other applications on your computer. This separation lets Office 2010 coexist together with any existing version of Office that is already installed on your computer. There are also other benefits to Office Click-to-Run. For more information, visit the following Microsoft blog website

And:

> **What is the "Q:" drive?**
>
> Office 2010 Click-to-Run suite such as Office Starter 2010, Office Starter To-Go, Office Home and Student 2010, and Office Home and Business 2010 are based on some application virtualization technology. The Q: drive is the virtual file system drive where virtualized applications are located in the file system namespace. This Q: drive is not a typical drive. The Q: drive has no space that the user can access directly and is inaccessible from Windows Explorer or My Computer.

The article claims you shouldn't see the Q: drive, but I have seen it on a few machines.  It is not harmful and can be ignored.

Basically when you run your copy of office it runs from a virtual storage device (Q:) that downloads the data you need when you first ask for it, after that it is cached and your Office installation will be faster from then on.

Comment: That's it, I downloaded it some days ago. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your C: drive has occupied all your physical hard disk space or not.
And try to click on the left hand side of menu where Local Disk (Q:) is written. If you can access the drive from there, that means it's probably due to malfunctioning of some softwares,(probably a malware) you drive could not be accessed by double click and you have to open it every time from the explorer menu on left hand side.
I've been facing the similar problem in Windows 7. i couldn't open any of my non hard-disk drive through double click, and forced to use the explorer menu to open it. Although that was due to the malfunctioning of one of my virtual drive creator.